# Axis labels are not showing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, axis-labels

Can someone explain why xticks are not showing for the following code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a,b = np.arange(0,0.3,0.01),np.arange(0,0.3,0.01)
plt.plot(a,b,'k','Linewidth', 1.5)
plt.axis([0.15, 0.25, 0.05, 0.3])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line `plt.plot(a,b,'k','Linewidth', 1.5)` to `plt.plot(a,b,'k',Linewidth=1.5)`, then x-axis will show as it should

Comment: Thank you! But just out of curiosity, how do you know this?

Comment: No problem, well... [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) of course, you debug to find the line of code that is wrong, then check docs to write the right code : )